# Error when deleting requests if the page is refreshed

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, apprequests

Following Facebook's example code for deleting requests:

```
$deleted = $this->_facebook->api("/" . $reqId,'DELETE');
```

I can successfully delete requests when the user visits the app using the code above. However, if the user refreshes the page, which still contains the request ID in the URL, I get the error message below:

```
The entity backed by id XXXXXXX cannot be seen by the current viewer
```

Obviously, the request ID doesn't exist any more, as it has already been deleted once.

Is there a workaround/fix for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use a NONCE to prevent replays:  http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.base.doc%2Finfo%2Faes%2Fae%2Fcwbs_noncev6.html